# Stopping content overflow in 2 boxes css

Tags: html, css

hi all wonder if you could help me out, been beating my head up against a wall on this for a few days now.

i'm creating a web site and have 2 columns. when i add text to them instead of it automatically formatting to the size set of the column the text over flows. i have done some research on this and cant see where i have gone wrong. all of the examples i have looked at has the same code as me and doesnt have this error.

heres the code i have

css sheet

```
#leftcol {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fefcfc;
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
#rightcol {
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fefcfc;
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

html

```
<div id="leftcol">dfgdfgdfgfdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfsdfsfdsfdsfsdgfgfsadsdsdasdsadsssadsda</div>
<div id="rightcol" style= width "500" > 
  <div>
    <p> sadhjashdjashdjashdakjs</p>
    <p> sadsadkasjdfksajfksjfksdfjkdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffweweqweqwf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help would b appreciated

thanks

Comment: Right away I can tell you that `<div style= width "500">` is _NOT_ going to work right. Should spell `style="width: 500px"`. Either way, I don't see the point of this since you're setting the width for this element elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, try this:

```
#rightcol {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This will force long lines of text to break.

Note Czechnology's comment, you have some invalid code here `<div id="rightcol" style= width "500" >` should be `<div id="rightcol" style="width:500px">`, or not there at all preferably (use CSS).

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have removed the style width code out. only had that in whilst experimenting. sadly the css 'word-wrap' hasnt worked and my text stil lflows out of the box rather than to the next line. know there must be a simple answer but always hav problems with the basics and find the harder stuff eassier, lol.